# dry-rails how to use contract validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry-validation

after adding the gem [dry-rails](https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-rails/0.3/) to my rails application, I have defined a contract:

```
module Users
  module Contracts
    class New < ApplicationContract
      params do
        required(:todo).schema do
          required(:title).filled(:string)
          required(:items).array(:hash) do
            required(:name).filled(:string)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I don't know how to make this contract work. Let's say I have a controller named UsersController:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_user

      private
      def set_user
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

how can I make this controller use the contract New to get validation run?

Answer (score 0):

When I understand the example at https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-rails/blob/v0.5.0/spec/dummy/app/controllers/users_controller.rb correctly, you need to call `safe_params` instead of `params`

Specifically `safe_params.success?` or `safe_params[:id]`

Besides this, at the "HTTP boundary", dry recommends to use dry-schema instead of dry-validation.

The contract you mentioned is more for an operator